# Php command line script can't connect to server using MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this command line script I am trying to use. It adds image to an already present database and table. The server has Wamp server installed on it and I can access it from a different computer. But everytime I run the script the script just hangs when connecting.

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   $filename = $argv[1];
   //$filename="images/image10.jpg";
   $imgData = file_get_contents($filename);
   $size = getimagesize($filename);

   $servername="192.168.0.34";
   $username="root";
   $password="password";
   $dbname = "test";
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

   // check connection
   if($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }

   echo "Connection successful";

   // insert into table
   $sql = sprintf("insert into images(image_type, image, image_size, image_name) values('%s', '%s', '%d', '%s')",
   mysql_real_escape_string($size['mime']),
   mysql_real_escape_string($imgData),
   $size[3],
   mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['userfile']['name']));

   if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      echo "Inserted new image successfully";
   } else {
      echo "Error inserting image: " . $conn->error;
   }

   echo "Closing the connection";
   $conn = null;

   ?>
```

I have only installed php and php-mysql on the client. The client is running debian and the sever is running windows 7. Am I missing something else I need to install?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `mysqli` on your system. See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

Comment: I have it installed on my system. using php-mysql. is there more?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?